# React-native-gifted-chat change color under inputToolbar

Tags: react-native, user-interface, react-native-gifted-chat

I am using react-native-gifted-chat, and I am having a hard time figuring out how to color or add a view below the InputToolbar to resemble something like the second image below.

**This is what I have**

[image]

**This is what I am trying to do**

[image]

If anyone knows how I could get close to the second image that would be great. If someone could send a link to a similar example or any help at all is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cab use `renderInputToolbar` and set the height for the root view as long as it fills to the bottom:

```
import {LeftAction, ChatInput, SendButton} from 'react-native-gifted-chat'

...

minInputToolbarHeight={70}
renderInputToolbar={(props)=> (
    <View style={{ backgroundColor: COLORS.lighterblue, height: 200 }}>
        <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
            <LeftAction {...props} />
            <ChatInput {...props} />
            <SendButton {...props} />
        </View>
        <View></View>
    </View>
)}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: While this link may answer the question (Example link), it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: This is exactly what I done to make this work. I upvoted this not why someone would downvote the right answer. Thank you for Hieu for answering.